# Why visual studio delete non-related assemblies from Bin folder when rebuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assemblies, delete-file, bin

I have an asp.net mvc web application, and i have a reference to **SharpArch.Web** (one of the Sharp Architecture assemblies)

When i rebuild the project, and run it, an exception is thrown telling me that the **(Newtonsoft.Json.dll)** is missing from the Bin folder which is used by **(SharpArch.Web)**, so it's ok, i copied it, and every thing worked well.

When i try to rebuild the project again, the exception is thrown again, and the (**Newtonsoft.Json.dll**) assembly is deleted ??

Why did that happen? what does visual studio have to do with non-referenced assembly ?
and FYI, VS doesn't delete everything from Bin, just a specific assemblies !!!

and BTW i don't want to add a reference to (**Newtonsoft.Json.dll**), i don't like to reference an unused assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation on one solution I was working on. So I ended up putting those .dll's into a separate folder. In my case I named this folder "ServerAssemblies". Then I modifyed my project file (.csproj in my case) and added an "AfterRebuild" target. That way there is noe need to add references to unused assemblies to the project.

```
<Target Name="AfterRebuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ExtraAssemblies Include="$(SolutionDir)ServerAssemblies\**\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ExtraAssemblies)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)bin\"></Copy>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the Bin\ directory is reserved for mangling by Visual Studio. You'll have to put your assembly in a different location.

Comment: i have a folder called Lib, and all my necessary assemblies are located in this folder, and all my projects reference the assemblies in this folder.

Comment: i'm sorry but i didn't get what you mean by Probing ?